# Regular Expressions: Equivalent of \d for any letter in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any character equivalent of \d for letters in Regular Expressions? For instance if trying to find a numerical pattern of digits in the form `"(111) 111-1111"` this code works:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\(\d\d\d) (\d\d\d\-\d\d\d)')
```

But how would you rewrite this code if the pattern digits are letters instead of numbers? In other words, how can the above code be changed so that it can match lettters of the pattern `"(abc) efg-hijk"`?

Comment: letters as in "latin letters without diacritics"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the following a shot:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\([a-zA-Z]{3}\)) ([a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{3})')
```

You can see the explanation, and edit and test it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/bHXPlX/1).

Answer (score 3):

First you have to decide what you actually mean by "letters", because there are a lot more letters in Unicode than there are in the English version of the Latin alphabet.

If you just want the English ones, that's as simple as `[A-Za-z]`, but there's no `\` shortcut for it.

If you use the `regex` module in Python instead of the `re` module, you can directly use Unicode metadata and ask for any character with a given property. In that case, `\p{Letter}` will do the trick. You'll have to install `regex` first, though, for example with `pip install regex`.

Also, note that you can match multiples of a regex without repeating it using the `{m,n}` quantifier syntax; your example could be written:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\(\d{3}) (\d{3}-\d{3}')
```

which should make using something longer in place of `\d` a little less painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example for the answer by Mark Reed to find your combination of letters, including letters with accents.

```
import regex

pattern = regex.compile(r'\p{L}{3} \p{L}{3}-\p{L}{4}')

matches = pattern.findall("ábç déf-ghíj")
print(matches)  # Output: ['ábç déf-ghíj']
```

source: straight from ChatGPT, verified in Pyhton